# Confusion between asymptotic direction and asymptotic line

Tags: differential-geometry

It is well-known that an asymptotic direction in $p \in S$ is a tangent vector on which the normal curvature vanishes. Furthermore, an asymptotic line in $S$ is a curve such that for any of its points the normal curvature vanishes (i.e. $Q(\sigma'(t))=0$ for every $t \in I$). Ok, assume that in a point $p$ there is an asymptotic direction. Is it possible to deduce the existence of an asymptotic line passing through $p$?